# Fast way to get all pairs of matrix column element-wise products

Tags: r, matrix, product

Let's say I have a numerical `matrix`:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 100)
```

I want to generate all vectors that are the result of the element-wise product of all unique pairs of vectors in `mat`.

How can we improve below code:

```
all.pairs <- t(combn(1:ncol(mat), 2))

res <-
  do.call(cbind,
          lapply(1:nrow(all.pairs),
                 function(p) mat[, all.pairs[p, 1]] * mat[, all.pairs[p, 2]]))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We could do:

```
n <- ncol(mat)
lst <- lapply(1:n, function (i) mat[,i] * mat[,i:n])
do.call(cbind, lst)
```

Or, here is an even faster way:

```
n <- ncol(mat)
j1 <- rep.int(1:n, n:1)
j2 <- sequence(n:1) - 1L + j1
mat[, j1] * mat[, j2]
```

---

Note, the above will include the multiplication of a column to itself. If you want to forbid that, use

```
n <- ncol(mat)
lst <- lapply(1:(n-1), function (i) mat[,i] * mat[,(i+1):n])
do.call(cbind, lst)
```

and

```
n <- ncol(mat)
j1 <- rep.int(1:(n-1), (n-1):1)
j2 <- sequence((n-1):1) + j1
mat[, j1] * mat[, j2]
```

---

Actually, `j1` and `j2` created above are just the 1st and 2nd row of `combn(1:ncol(mat),2)`. So, if you still want to stay with `combn`, use

```
all.pairs <- combn(1:ncol(mat),2)
mat[, all.pairs[1,]] * mat[, all.pairs[2,]]
```